# Reload works on localhost but not on heroku url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, react-router

When I run my web app locally and try to reload/refresh the same page it works fine.
But when I run the app on Heroku URL it runs but when I refresh/reload the same page on Heroku it gives back

> Internal Server Error with a status code of 500.

I have used `react-router`. But I think the problem is somewhere with the backend in `node/express.`

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";
import path from "path";

import postRoutes from "./routes/posts.js";
import userRoutes from "./routes/user.js";

const app = express();
dotenv.config();

app.use(express.json({
  extended: true,
  limit: "30mb"
}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
  limit: "30mb"
}));

app.use(cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  if ("OPTIONS" == req.method) {
    res.send(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

// Have Node serve the files for our built React app
app.use(express.static("client/build"));

app.use("/posts", postRoutes);
app.use("/user", userRoutes);
app.get("/api", (req, res) => res.send("Hello to memories API"));

// All other GET requests not handled before will return our React app
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Server is running on port:" + PORT))
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);
```

```js
2021 - 08 - 16 T08: 42: 37.915625 + 00: 00 heroku[router]: at = info method = GET path = "/posts"
host = obscure - escarpment - 66598. herokuapp.com request_id = 04530 f95 - 56 a2 - 4 b65 - 9065 - 73 f9867adc40 fwd = "1.187.251.82"
dyno = web .1 connect = 2 ms service = 5 ms status = 500 bytes = 629 protocol = https
2021 - 08 - 16 T08: 42: 37.918709 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
2021 - 08 - 16 T08: 42: 37.918721 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: at file: ///app/index.js:45:28
2021 - 08 - 16 T08: 42: 37.918722 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: at Layer.handle[as handle_request](/app/node_modules / express / lib / router / layer.js: 95: 5)
2021 - 08 - 16 T08: 42: 37.918726 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: at next(/app/node_modules / express / lib / router / route.js: 137: 13)
2021 - 08 - 16 T08: 42: 37.918727 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: at Route.dispatch(/app/node_modules / express / lib / router / route.js: 112: 3)
2021 - 08 - 16 T08: 42: 37.918727 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: at Layer.handle[as handle_request](/app/node_modules / express / lib / router / layer.js: 95: 5)
2021 - 08 - 16 T08: 42: 37.918728 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: at / app / node_modules / express / lib / router / index.js: 281: 22
2021 - 08 - 16 T08: 42: 37.918729 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: at param(/app/node_modules / express / lib / router / index.js: 354: 14)
2021 - 08 - 16 T08: 42: 37.918729 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: at param(/app/node_modules / express / lib / router / index.js: 365: 14)
2021 - 08 - 16 T08: 42: 37.918729 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: at Function.process_params(/app/node_modules / express / lib / router / index.js: 410: 3)
2021 - 08 - 16 T08: 42: 37.918730 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: at next(/app/node_modules / express / lib / router / index.js: 275: 10)
2021 - 08 - 16 T08: 42: 37.918730 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: at SendStream.error(/app/node_modules / serve - static / index.js: 121: 7)
2021 - 08 - 16 T08: 42: 37.918731 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: at SendStream.emit(events.js: 376: 20)
2021 - 08 - 16 T08: 42: 37.918731 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: at SendStream.error(/app/node_modules / send / index.js: 270: 17)
2021 - 08 - 16 T08: 42: 37.918732 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: at SendStream.onStatError(/app/node_modules / send / index.js: 421: 12)
2021 - 08 - 16 T08: 42: 37.918732 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: at next(/app/node_modules / send / index.js: 735: 16)
2021 - 08 - 16 T08: 42: 37.918732 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: at onstat(/app/node_modules / send / index.js: 724: 14)
```

Comment: It is near impossible to help you, since you haven't added any code.

Comment: Step 1. Look at your heroku logs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Comment: wait why you hosted react in Heroku, use netlify or vercel